# :not and :first-child

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

In a `for` loop I replace the content of a div with another and I add a class to it.

Example:

```
<div class="page">Loading..</div>
<div class="page">Loading..</div>
<div class="page">Loading..</div>
```

And jQuery:

```
$(".page:not(.active):first-child").html("Loaded.").addlass(".active");
```

It works only for the first. How can I do it? They have to be all "Loaded" in the end.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Replace it with

```
$(".page:not(.active)").eq(0).html("Loaded.").addClass("active");
```

To add a class you don't need the dot and `:first-child` only works for the first child element while you need the first element of the filtered set.

Comment: @A.V He obviously calls his function more than once, wanting to change the div one after the other.

Comment: Thanks dude! To all: Sry, it was obv that I used "first-child" to select the first element and not all

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
$(".page:not(.active)").html("Loaded.").addClass("active");
```

Answer (score -1):

change your jquery to

```
 $(".page:not(.active)").html("Loaded.").addclass("active");
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NIkhar/neyee/)